# Why were my answers deleted? duplicate / not much more than a link or what reason?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, link-only-answers, duplicate-answers

Why was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27194533/4288004) answer from me deleted?
Was it because I also posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27194492/4288004)(was deleted, too), but then why remove both answers? I couldn't comment on these answers and I thought it would be helpful to not only have an example for getting the location but for geofences, too, which is also a part of the location services.
Was it because I wasn't quoting the source code? I suggested to improve the answer as I couldn't get the formatting right when quoting the code and someone could have added it, but it was now answered properly.
Additionally, I provided information, that the link from the OP now included the requested example.
As it was an unanswered question I think valuable information was deleted.

Here's the answer 1 from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27194533/4288004):

> Here's my example for the Geofencing API that switches WiFi on when
>   entering the Geofence, replace the latitude and longitude with your
>   desired geofence center (just ignore the .old files in the repo, these
>   are old location implementations):
>
> [Main](https://github.com/nerdome/LocationSwitcher/blob/master/src/de/adornis/de/locationswitcher/Main.java)
>   [GeofenceReceiver](https://github.com/nerdome/LocationSwitcher/blob/master/src/de/adornis/de/locationswitcher/GeofenceReceiver.java)
>
> I used the documentation from
>   [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingApi.html)
>   and clicked my way through the classes used....
>
> Also, the
>   [example](https://github.com/jdellinger/AnDevConNov2014-LocationServicesDemoProject/tree/newapi)
>   you mentioned in your question now uses the new API! You could update
>   that in your question.
>
> If someone gets the formatting right, he can include the code here.

and answer 2 from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27194492/4288004):

> Here's my example for the Geofencing API that switches WiFi on when
>   entering the Geofence, replace the latitude and longitude with your
>   desired geofence center (just ignore the .old files in the repo, these
>   are old location implementations):
>
> [Main](https://github.com/nerdome/LocationSwitcher/blob/master/src/de/adornis/de/locationswitcher/Main.java)
>   [GeofenceReceiver](https://github.com/nerdome/LocationSwitcher/blob/master/src/de/adornis/de/locationswitcher/GeofenceReceiver.java)
>
> Also,
>   [this](https://github.com/jdellinger/AnDevConNov2014-LocationServicesDemoProject/tree/newapi)
>   example now uses the new API!
>
> I used the documentation from
>   [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingApi.html)
>   and clicked my way through the classes used....
>
> For probably more answers / examples showing up for geofencing, see
>   [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633796/android-locationservices-geofencingapi-example-usage/27194533)
>   question, that aims specifically towards geofences not the new
>   location API in general.
>
> If someone gets the formatting right, he can include the code here.

**I didn't receive an info, why it was deleted, is this normal?**
So I figured out here is the right place to ask.

**Why was / were my answer(s) (both) deleted and how can I improve it / them to fulfil the requirements?**

Comment: It's a link only answer.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/165773)**

Comment: EDIT: just saw the new comment now /EDIT
So should I have included the code bad formatted instead? Why is it deleted rather than keeping the information and free for improvement?
Is it normal that you don't get any information about why an answer was deleted?
Why someone could have downvoted? I'm just trying to understand what I should have done and I thought it is information worth sharing and it is not an link only answer anymore.How can I improve this meta question?

Comment: @gnat Doesn't this "Just remember: if the text of the post contains an honest attempt at answering the question, then it is an answer - so don't flag it otherwise, and if you do, don't complain if your flag gets declined. " appliy to my answer?

Comment: apparently, readers didn't consider text in deleted answers a "honest attempt"

Comment: I think that's not the case, I provided the only answer und it was exactly the information the author was looking for. Or why is it not an honest attempt if I also tried to copy the code but couldn't get the formatting right?

Answer (score 8):

[One of your answers was deleted by a moderator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633796/android-locationservices-geofencingapi-example-usage/27194533#27194533) because you spammed [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611977/android-locationclient-class-is-deprecated-but-used-in-documentation/27194492#27194492) to multiple questions, raising a 'duplicate answer 'flag' in the moderator queue.

If you see two questions that are so similar that you believe the same answer applies, your best bet is to vote to close or flag to close the question as a duplicate.

If you do not have the reputation to do that, either tailor your answer to the specific question asked, or leave a comment pointing to your answer.

Your other answer has a few issues:

1. It doesn't really look like an answer. I'm not sure what it is, but it doesn't seem to be an answer.  I don't see how it addresses the question, and an outsider would have a hard time seeing how you're answering the question.
2. It is comprised of links to other locations where the answer might be.  That has a few issues:

   - Those links could die, rendering your post useless
   - A user now has to click multiple places to figure out if your post addresses their issue (a bad user experience)

To have your questions undeleted:

- Tailor them to the question asked (don't copy/paste the same answer to multiple questions)
- Improve your answer to not be a collection of links, but to actually address the specfic issue the OP has; solve it in the answer, and then link to the other pages as supplementary information.

Comment: I didn't receive an info, why it was deleted, is this normal?
I tried to tailor the answer to the questions if you read it again.
My best suggestion would be to link to the other question / answer in an answer because this way it is reachable as long as the answer itself is reachable and the always up to date answer (because it's only one) fairly outweighs the additonal click that needs to be done. If you have a long thread like that an answer is usually a lot more easy to find than a comment. Or edit the top answer with the link to the closely related questios?

Comment: So should I have included the code bad formatted instead in the other answer? Why is it deleted rather than keeping the information and free for improvement?
See comment to my question above: "Doesn't this "Just remember: if the text of the post contains an honest attempt at answering the question, then it is an answer - so don't flag it otherwise, and if you do, don't complain if your flag gets declined. " appliy to my answer?"

Comment: @fightcookie you are expected to be notified if low quality queue reviewers voted to delete as link-only answer, [according to SE team this generates comments visible to author](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197543/low-quality-but-looks-salvageable-trying-to-pick-between-looks-good-and-re#comment625668_197568)

Answer (score 5):

We want answers to be actual answers. That is, the person asking a question should be able to determine if what you say answers their question by just reading through your answer.

Your answer however has the form of "look over there, check this thing on another site, and go there as well". Not only is it inconvenient, but the site itself didn't gain anything of value, and if your links ever go dead there is nothing left.

We call those "link-only answers". You do risk downvotes for them, and they may be deleted. Make your answers self-contained. Links aren't bad, but should only be used in addition to your answer.

Comment: I didn't receive an info, why it was deleted, is this normal?
So should I have included the code bad formatted instead in the other answer? Why is it deleted rather than keeping the information and free for improvement? See comment to my question above: "Doesn't this "Just remember: if the text of the post contains an honest attempt at answering the question, then it is an answer - so don't flag it otherwise, and if you do, don't complain if your flag gets declined. " appliy to my answer?" and see comment to the other answer, too.

Comment: *Doesn't this <..> apply to my answer?* It indeed does not. Link-only answers do not attempt to answer the question, they attempt to redirect the OP to some site that perhaps has an answer to the question, or may have otherwise useful information on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

The answers from George and Bart already explained why your answer was deleted. But I think there is a more generic part to your question that is worth discussing.

In my opinion, you absolutely should have been given a reason why your post was deleted. It might be clear to people who spend a lot of time on this site, and on meta, but we can't assume that every user has the same in depth knowledge of site guidelines. If somebody makes a genuine effort to answer a question, but it needs to be deleted because it does not meet the guidelines, they should be given feedback on what they missed. This way, they know how to fix that answer.
Or even more importantly, what they need to do better when posting answers in the future.

To give you some background on what happens when an answer is flagged, there are two main scenarios:

- It goes into the Low Quality review queue, where users with at least 3k rep can vote on the post. If they vote to delete the answer, they can select from a number of different reasons. For each reason they choose, there's a different canned comment that briefly explains the problem with the post, with links to help topics.
- It is handled by a diamond moderator. They can delete the question if they decide that it's the right course of action. In this case, there will generally be no comment explaining why the post was deleted.
- (Answers can also be deleted with votes from 20k rep users. I'm not sure how exactly that process works.)

It would make sense to me to also have the automated canned comment when a moderator deletes an answer. After a bit of searching, I found a post on MSE that proposes exactly that:

[Give moderators the option to select a deletion reason when removing posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193789/give-moderators-the-option-to-select-a-deletion-reason-when-removing-posts)

You should upvote it if you believe that it would be a useful change. It has a good number of upvotes already.

I'm not advocating that a reason must be given for all deleted answers. If somebody posts "I like nachos with cheese" (real example, I didn't make that up), deleting without any explanation is perfectly fine.

Comment: It doesn't really require in-depth knowledge though. The ["How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page states *"Provide context for links. Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."* ... but admittedly, people would have to read that first.